# Grunt + Browser sync: no CSS injection or ghost mode

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, browser-sync

I'm encountering some confusing issues with getting the browser sync plugin for Grunt to work properly. I have thoroughly read the docs and followed examples but there are a couple of things that won't work:
1) I'm not getting any CSS injection. I know I am running the plugin alongside a watch task, but I have `watchTask: true` set and my terminal is showing that bS is identifying the change to my CSS, it's just not reloading the browser.
2) None of the ghost mode options seem to work for me. I have set them all to true but, much like the livereload feature, I'm not able to make it work.

Here is my current Gruntfile:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      less : {
        files: ['static/css/less/*.less'],
        tasks: ['less']
      },
      html : {
        files: ['*.html']
      },
      js : {
        files: ['static/js/*.js']
      }
    },
    less: {
      development: {
          options: {
              paths: ["css"],
              compress: true,
              yuicompress: true,
              optimization: 2
          },
          files: {
            "static/css/styles.css": "static/css/less/styles.less"
          }
      }
    },
    browserSync: {
      default_options: {
        bsFiles: {
          src: [
            "static/css/*.css",
            "*.html"
          ]
        },
        options: {
          watchTask: true,
          server: {
            baseDir: "./"
          },
          ghostMode: {
              clicks: true,
              forms: true,
              scroll: true  
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');

  // Launch BrowserSync + watch task
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserSync', 'watch']);
};
```

Any help would be really appreciated